# Variable-sized memory space in ARM64 assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, arm64, gnu-assembler

I currently have a variable externally `.extern length`, which is defined in a separate C file.
And the arm64 assembly code below is a fixed size continuous memory:

```
spaceBottom:
    .space  0x1000
spaceTop:
```

Is there a way to set the size of this memory space to be "length" (instead of 0x1000) in arm64 assembly?

Comment: Sure, if `length` is an assemble-time constant you defined earlier in the file (or one you `.include`).  But if you want the value of bytes assembled into some section already, no, you can't read them back even at link time.  You could use `.set` or `.equ` to give a symbol an integer value that the linker could see, and that might work to avoid needing `.include` (or with a `.S`, C-preprocessor `#include`).

Comment: You can do this with trickery in linker scripts, but it is not how you are supposed to do things.

Comment: You can write code that will scan source and replace the value.  If `length` is dynamic, then you need a dynamic allocator.  If `length` is compile constant, then you can use defines, linker file, etc.  Another technique is to run the assembler file through the 'C' pre-processor to replace `#define length` with a constant.  This can be shared between assembler and 'C'.  It needs to be pre-process to nothing, so the header should avoid prototypes, etc. through omission or pre-processor conditions.

Comment: `length` is a compile constant

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have noted, you could just put it in a header file and use that.

header.h:

```c
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#define MY_LENGTH 0x1000

#endif
```

source.c:

```c
#include "header.h"

const unsigned int length = MY_LENGTH;
```

asm.S:

```
#include "header.h"

.data

spaceBottom:
    .space MY_LENGTH
spaceTop:
```

Note that in order for this to work with the GNU toolchain, the `.S` suffix must be uppercase.

A different option would be to move the `length` variable to assembly to begin with, then you could construct its value from the `spaceTop` and `spaceBottom` symbols like so:

```
.data

spaceBottom:
    .space 0x1000
spaceTop:

.section .rodata

length:
    .4byte spaceTop - spaceBottom
```

Then you'd just need a declaration in a header file to fix up the C end:

```c
extern const unsigned int length;
```